# Cookies aren't stored fast enough by mozilla firefox?

Tags: php, firefox, cookies, mozilla

So I have some session checking to see if it's not stolen using PHP. I set a request count as a value in the session array and send a cookie with same value to the client. If the values don't match then someone has interfered.

The problem is that sometimes the values don't match and I doubt someone stole the session and used it. Is it possible that Firefox is slow in storing the cookies?
I'm asking this because I have a broken mouse which click-spams when I click. When I use the touchpad I never disconnect from the app.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Browsers usually have multiple, simultaneous connections open to the same website and download resources in parallel. Trying to count requests is certain to create race conditions.

If you want to reduce the chances of session hijacking, use SSL for your data transfer.

Comment: Eventually ill buy a ssl certificate but wanted to try and make a simple checking...i guess i'm kinda limited... ty for your answer

Answer (score 1):

It's probably due to the click-spamming.  The cookie will be sent in the response, but if you interrupt the response before the browser fully loads the page, it will probably not process and store the cookie.  Of course the session will have been updated because it is updated on the server before the request is sent (on php shutdown).

This would probably cause a condition where

- PHP session value is set
- cookie with same value is sent
- browser request interrupted by a fast click
- cookie never gets saved
- request is sent and session value updates / values don't match at this point

You should probably find a more reliable method for detecting session hijacking, i.e. SSL.